# Chisel bootcamp 3.2 Muxes result wrong?

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

Here is the code in Chisel Bootcamp:

```
Driver(() => new Module {
    // Example circuit using Mux1H
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
      val in_sels = Input(Vec(2, Bool()))
      val in_bits = Input(Vec(2, UInt(8.W)))
      val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
    })
    io.out := Mux1H(io.in_sels, io.in_bits)
  }) { c => new PeekPokeTester(c) {
    poke(c.io.in_bits(0), 10)
    poke(c.io.in_bits(1), 20)

    // Select index 1
    poke(c.io.in_sels(0), 0)
    poke(c.io.in_sels(1), 1)
    println(s"in_sels=${peek(c.io.in_sels)}, out=${peek(c.io.out)}")

    // Select index 0
    poke(c.io.in_sels(0), 1)
    poke(c.io.in_sels(1), 0)
    println(s"in_sels=${peek(c.io.in_sels)}, out=${peek(c.io.out)}")

    // Select none (invalid)
    poke(c.io.in_sels(0), 0)
    poke(c.io.in_sels(1), 0)
    println(s"in_sels=${peek(c.io.in_sels)}, out=${peek(c.io.out)}")

    // Select both (invalid)
    poke(c.io.in_sels(0), 1)
    poke(c.io.in_sels(1), 1)
    println(s"in_sels=${peek(c.io.in_sels)}, out=${peek(c.io.out)}")
} }
```

And I got the result like this:

```
[info] [0.001] in_sels=Vector(0, 1), out=20
[info] [0.001] in_sels=Vector(1, 0), out=10
[info] [0.002] in_sels=Vector(0, 0), out=0
[info] [0.002] in_sels=Vector(1, 1), out=30
```

Why the result is 30 when select = (1, 1) ?
PS: 30 is a random num, not the result 10 + 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mux1H`'s behavior is undefined when more than one of its selects is high. If you look into the implementation it is using an `or` to create the behavior. 30 is the result of the 10 | 20. But, again, because it's undefined you cannot rely on this outcome when multiple selects are high.